# How to get full length on Vine ID

Tags: php, vine

When I've tried to call Vine Api, I've getting this id formatted eg. `1.3367327754366E+18`. How can I get real vine id string using PHP?

Comment: That's a string improperly converted to number. If you have that as soon as you get the API response, there's nothing you can do to recover the original value: that API is broken and cannot be used.

Comment: Is it a hex code being cast to a floating point number? What does a Vine ID look like?

Comment: Is this the correct user id? `1336732775436600064` (cast it to int or don't cast it to float if it's your script that's doing it)